# How to develop a responsive full grid system by using css grid in scss?

Tags: css, sass

I am trying to develop a 12 column grid system by using CSS grid.
I am developing this grid mechanism in scss.
What I want My row will behave differently ?

For example:

For larger screens/devices, more than 1200, I want to use 12 columns.
For Portrait Tablets, I want to use 6 to 8 columns.
and for Mobile devices, I want to use 4 columns.

This is my `Package.json`

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.2.1",
    "node-sass": "^7.0.1",
    "react": "^18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.3.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

This is my `_header.scss`

```
header{
    background-color: var(--defaultbgcolor);
    color:var(--white);
    height: 55px;
   
    // height: 12vh;

    /*background-image: linear-gradient(
        to right bottom,
        rgba($color-primary-light, 0.8),
        rgba($color-primary-dark, 0.8))*//*,
    url(../img/hero-small.jpg)
    background-size: cover;*/

    @include respond(phone) {
        height: 30px;
    }

    @include respond(tab-port) {
        height: 39px;
    }

    .header{    
        align-self: center;
        justify-self:end;  
        grid-column: 1 / 1;      
        @include respond(phone) {
            grid-column: 1 / 1;
            grid-row: 1;
            align-self: center;
            justify-self:start; 
            padding-left:5px; 
        }  

        @include respond(tab-port) {
            grid-column: 1 / 1;
            grid-row: 1;
            align-self: center;
            justify-self:start; 
            padding-left:5px; 
        }

        img{
            object-fit: contain;
            width:50px;
            height:50px;
        }        
    }  
    
    .logo-tagline{
        align-self: center;
        justify-self: end;    
        @include respond(phone) {
            grid-column: 1 / 1;
            grid-row: 1;
            align-self: center;
            justify-self: end;   
        }   

        @include respond(tab-port) {
            grid-column: 1 / 1;
            grid-row: 1;
            align-self: center;
            justify-self: end;   
        }   
    }

    .SearchBox{
        align-self: center;
        justify-self: stretch;           
        grid-column: 3 / 9;

        @include respond(phone) {
            grid-column: 1 / 3;
            grid-row: 2;
            justify-self: stretch;              
        }

        @include respond(tab-port) {
            grid-column: 2 / 3;
            grid-row: 1;
            justify-self: stretch;              
        }

        input[type="search"] {
            width: 100%;       
            padding: 12px 20px;
            @include respond(phone) {
                padding: 5px 2px;
            }

            @include respond(tab-port) {
                padding: 5px 2px;
            }
            //border: 1px solid black;
            //border-radius: 10px;
            -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
            transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;

            &:focus {                
                //border: 1px solid whitesmoke;
                border-bottom: 1px solid whitesmoke;
              }
        }
    }
    .Search-Icon{
        align-self: center;
        justify-self: start; 
        margin-left: 23px; 
        @include respond(phone) {
            margin-left: 0; 
            grid-column: 3/4;
            grid-row:2;
            justify-self: stretch; 
        }   
        
        @include respond(tab-port) {
            margin-left: 0; 
            grid-column: 3/4;
            grid-row:1;
            justify-self: stretch; 
        } 
        button{
            padding: 11px 20px;  
            @include respond(phone) {
                padding: 4px 0px;  
                width:100%;
            }

            @include respond(tab-port) {
                padding: 4px 0px;  
                width:100%;
            }
        }
    }

    .notify{
        align-self: center;
        justify-self: stretch;
        @include respond(phone) {
            grid-column: 2 / 3;
            grid-row:1;
            justify-self: stretch;
        }

        @include respond(tab-port) {
            grid-column: 4 / 5;
            grid-row:1;
            justify-self: stretch;
        }
        svg{
            width:2em;
            height:2em;
        }
    .notification {
        //background-color: #555;
        background-color: transparent;
        color: white;
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: 8px 15px;
        position: relative;
        //display: inline-block;
        border-radius: 2px;

        @include respond(phone) {
            padding: 6px 15px;
       } 

       @include respond(tab-port) {
        padding: 6px 15px;
   } 

        &:hover {
            background: var(--white);
          }

          .badge {
            position: absolute;
            //top: -10px;
            top: -6px;
            right: -10px;
            padding: 5px 10px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            background-color: var(--orange);
            color: white;
          }
      }
    }  
    
    .logout-section{
        align-self: center;
        justify-self: flex-start;         
        grid-column: 11/12;
        @include respond(phone) {
            margin-left: 0; 
            grid-column: 3/4;
            grid-row:1;
            justify-self: flex-start; 
        }  
        
        @include respond(tab-port) {
            margin-left: 0; 
            grid-column: 5/6;
            grid-row:1;
            justify-self: flex-start; 
        }  
    }
       
}

.logo-first{
    font-size:2.25rem;   
}
```

and this is mixin

```
@mixin respond($breakpoint) {
    @if $breakpoint == phone {
        @media only screen and (max-width: 37.5em) { @content };    //600px
    }
    @if $breakpoint == tab-port {
        @media only screen and (max-width: 56.25em) { @content };     //900px
    }
    @if $breakpoint == tab-land {
        @media only screen and (max-width: 75em) { @content };    //1200px
    }
    @if $breakpoint == big-desktop {
        @media only screen and (min-width: 112.5em) { @content };    //1800
    }
}
```

and this is my `_fullgrid.scss`

```
.row {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(12, [col-start] minmax(150px, 1fr));
    gap: 20px;

    @include respond(phone) {
      grid-template-columns: repeat(4, [col-start] minmax(140px, 1fr));
      gap: 6px;
    }

    @include respond(tab-port) {
      grid-template-columns: repeat(6, [col-start] minmax(136.67px, 1fr));
      gap: 6px;
    } 
    //align-items: center;
    //justify-content: center;
    & > * {      
      //grid-column: col-start / span 12;
      
      @include respond(phone) {
        grid-column: col-start / span 12;
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
      } 
    }
  }
```

and this is the plain html for header

```
 <header className="row">
      <div className="header"><h1 class="logo-first">Hello</h1>      
     </div>
     <div className='logo-tagline'> World </div>
     <div className='SearchBox'> <input type="search" placeholder="Search.."/></div>
     <div className='Search-Icon'><button type="submit"></button></div>
     <div className="notify">
          <a href="#" class="notification">
            alert
            <span class="badge">6</span>
          </a>
          <a href="#" class="notification">
            comments
            <span class="badge">3</span>
          </a>
     </div>    
       <div className='logout-section'>
      </div>
 </header>
```

My above logic mix the content in different devices. for example it works fine for bigger screens
and portrait-tablets but it doesn't work good in mobile devices.

What expert people suggest me ?